# Is there a listener for when a child process has started?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, metrics, child-process

I am currently using the async module (https://github.com/caolan/async) combined with child_process.exec(). Specifically I am using async.parallelLimit, which for one of its parameters accepts an array of tasks (functions to execute). One item in my array of tasks looks something like this:

```
var tasks = [];
tasks.push(function() {
    var startTime = Date.now();
    exec('do the thing', function(err, stdout, stderr) {
        var endTime = Date.now();
        var timeTaken = endTime - startTime;
    });
});
```

Then after I create my array of tasks (the above being an example of one task), I then send them off to 
async

```
async.parallelLimit(tasks, 2 /*maxWorkers*/, callback)
```

What I notice is whenever I checkout the total time taken, it is always way off...

I've looked at the child_process.spawn() events but none of them listen to an emitter 'open', though there is 'close'.

What I would like to do is somehow add an event listener to child_process() so I know exactly when the process has been started so I can correctly get timestamps of the start of the process, and the end of the process.

**UPDATE**:

So after doing some more testing, I realized I have been doing this correctly all along, I had just forgotten to divide by 1000 since the end result is in milliseconds. It was late at night....>.<

Answer (score 1):

What about prefixing your command with `time` and parsing that output (which can be custom formatted for easier parsing) instead?

Comment: While this could work, I'd rather not have to deal with parsing output for total time taken. Also I need two timestamps (beginning/end)

Answer (score 1):

I would open server socket on the parent process and children could notify to that socket any data anytime giving the effect of async notification.

Comment: While I tested this method (using spawn instead of exec), it did indeed work, though I realized the true issue (not converting my milliseconds to seconds).

Answer (score 0):

So after doing some more testing, I realized I have been doing this correctly all along, I had just forgotten to divide by 1000 since the end result is in milliseconds. It was late at night....>.<

Both child_process.exec and child_process.spawn both worked correctly after I had realized my noobish mistake of not converting milliseconds to seconds.